MAUI Project Unable to Build (after system restore)
So I had some computer trouble (Windows wouldn't start) and needed to perform a Windows Restore to restore to an earlier point in time with the recovery tool (hard restart 3x).
Prior to the recovery process. I had a Maui project which built just fine in Visual Studio.
After the recovery, Visual Studio struggled with updates so I uninstalled Visual Studio 2022 Community, and the VS Installer (as much as one can possibly uninstall these things) using Add/Remove Programs, and then put them back in by downloading from the web and running the installer.  Checking off the MAUI tools box when performing the installation.
After the reinstall, all my other .NET 8 projects build fine, but the MAUI project is struggling immensely.
dotnet restore results in a whole slew of error messages that look like this (these messages also appear in the build errors window of Visual Studio):
[C:\Development\VMJX\VisualMusicJukeboxX.sln]
C:\Development\VMJX\src\RemoteControl\RemoteControl.csproj : error NU1202: Package Xamarin.AndroidX.LocalBroadcastManager 1.1.0.7 is not compatible with net8.0-android34.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0) / maccatalyst-x64. Package Xamarin.AndroidX.LocalBroadcastManager 1.1.0.7 does not support any target frameworks. 
...
[C:\Development\VMJX\VisualMusicJukeboxX.sln]
C:\Development\VMJX\src\RemoteControl\RemoteControl.csproj : error NU1202: Package CommunityToolkit.Maui 9.1.0 is not compatible with net8.0-maccatalyst18.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0) / android-x64. Package CommunityToolkit.Maui 9.1.0 does not support any target frameworks. 
...
[C:\Development\VMJX\VisualMusicJukeboxX.sln]
C:\Development\VMJX\src\RemoteControl\RemoteControl.csproj : error NU1202: Package Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection.Ktx 1.2.0.9 is not compatible with net8.0-android34.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0) / iossimulator-x64. Package Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection.Ktx 1.2.0.9 does not support any target frameworks. 

^ just a minor excerpt, there are hundreds of them spanning various targets and packages
This is the result of dotnet workload list (I manually ran dotnet workload install maui in hopes to fix the issue.  It has not helped.):
Installed Workload Id      Manifest Version       Installation Source
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
android                    34.0.138/8.0.100       SDK 8.0.400, VS 17.11.35312.102
aspire                     8.2.1/8.0.100          SDK 8.0.400, VS 17.11.35312.102
ios                        18.0.8303/8.0.100      SDK 8.0.400, VS 17.11.35312.102
maccatalyst                18.0.8303/8.0.100      SDK 8.0.400, VS 17.11.35312.102
maui                       8.0.82/8.0.100         SDK 8.0.400
maui-windows               8.0.82/8.0.100         SDK 8.0.400, VS 17.11.35312.102

Any help would be appreciated, I'm not sure what part of my system is missing or needs to be repaired in order to correctly build this project.
To eliminate any ambiguity, I have created a brand new MAUI project and it's not able to build, so it has nothing to do with my actual source code.

Have you tried Repair  in Visual Studio Installer?

I have created a brand new MAUI project and it's not able to build Did it throw any error?

I did try repair, yes, took about 20 minutes, ran through what seemed like an entire reinstallation, and did not fix the problem at all :-/.
Creating the new project itself did not throw any errors, but as soon as it was created there were build errors.  The build errors were the same as the nuget restore errors listed above.

Make sure you follow the steps in Installation. If it still does not work, we commend you Report a problem with the Visual Studio product or installer.
